# Maven scm and svn

Tags: maven, svn, maven-scm

I am having trouble accessing the svn revision number through Maven. The only real help I've received from the SCM usage page is the following:

```
<scm>
    <connection>scm:svn:http://somerepository.com/svn_repo/trunk</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:svn:https://somerepository.com/svn_repo/trunk</developerConnection>
    <tag>HEAD</tag>
    <url>http://somerepository.com/view.cvs</url>
</scm>
```

This means nothing to me as I can't figure out what connection, developerConnection, and url mean. I simply plugged in the url to my repo for all 3 elements. I also don't know why Maven does not ask me for the username and password for the repository.

I am very new to Maven and might be asking a very basic question but would appreciate a full explanation as to how I am to access the svn repo.

Comment: Does this answer your question? http://stackoverflow.com/a/35676704/1743880

Comment: Hi @Tunaki its nice to see you here answering my questions again! I'm afraid that does not answer my question however :( , I really only need to connect to my repository but have no clue what any of the elements mean?

Comment: The docs http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#SCM are quite clear. `connection` and `developerConnection` point to the SVN repository URL, `tag` is optional, you don't need it, and `url` is an URL to an publicly browsable repository.

Comment: What if my repository is not publicly browsable? There lies my confusion. I am using a server built by my company that requires a username/password to access the repo.

Comment: You can't put whatever non-sense you want in that, it's just for informational purposes although I've never written anything that didn't look like a URL, even if it didn't really exist :D

Comment: What I'm really trying to do is add my svn revision number to a jar manifest [https://maven.apache.org/plugin-developers/cookbook/add-svn-revision-to-manifest.html] but I can't do so because of an error that reads 'the scm url cannot be null'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105609/discussion-between-max-and-tunaki).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I would begin by clarifying the usage of *Maven* which seems to cause the confusion in your case:

> *Apache Maven* is a software project management tool... that can manage the project's build.

*Apache Maven* has nothing to do with your revisions being pushed to your source code management system (*SVN* in your case).

Typically, you'll be pushing your changes through an IDE (*Eclipse*, *IntelliJ IDEA* and alike) or through a command line to your *SVN* repository and you **won't in any way** be pushing those changes through *Maven* in which case you'll be breaking its usage purpose.

Now comes the question, **why you may need then those SCM related properties?**
The answer is simple and should be relevant since *Maven* is a project build tool, it must handle your project release cycle which is final piece of the project build cycle... And it won't be able to do it in coherent way without **updating your remote project informations** since you are using an *SCM* remote repository.

Now back to those *SCM* related properties, and what do they mean:

- ***connection***: an URL connection endpoint to your *SCM* repository and which will only used for **read** access.
- ***developerConnection***: an URL connection endpoint to your *SCM* repository and which will be used for **write** access. (That's what a developer role is intended to do after all, *push changes to the repository*).
- ***tag***: it specifies the tag under which the project lives and I've seen only *HEAD* being used in there and assume would be the default.
- ***url***: it specifies a **browsable** repository, such as the one going through ***viewvc*** (In most cases you can replace the */svn/* path under your connection URL with */viewvc/*)

Answer (score 0):

**SCM** (**S**oftware **C**onfiguration **M**anagement, also called **S**ource **C**ode/**C**ontrol **M**anagement or, succinctly, version control) is an integral part of any healthy project. If your Maven project uses an SCM system (it does, doesn't it?) then here is where you would place that information into the POM.

`connection`, `developerConnection`: The two connection elements convey to how one is to connect to the version control system through Maven. Where `connection` requires read access for Maven to be able to find the source code (for example, an update), `developerConnection` requires a connection that will give write access. The Maven project has spawned another project named Maven SCM, which creates a common API for any SCMs that wish to implement it. The most popular are CVS and Subversion, however, there is a growing list of other supported SCMs. All SCM connections are made through a common URL structure.

```
scm:[provider]:[provider_specific]
```

Where provider is the type of SCM system. For example, connecting to a CVS repository may look like this:

```
scm:svn:https://somerepository.com/svn_repo/trunk
```

`tag`: Specifies the tag that this project lives under. HEAD (meaning, the SCM root) should be the default.

`url`: A publicly browsable repository. For example, via ViewCVS.

[Source](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#SCM)

Analogy : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9In7ysQJGBs